# I would like to know if I am encrypting the password correctly using OO

Tags: php

I have had this doubt for some time, because I don't know if I'm actually correctly encrypting the data, if I'm passing the correct values when instantiating the class and calling the function, and I also don't know if the return of the functions is correct, using `password_hash`
I believe it is correct, the hash works perfectly, but I would like to make sure that there is nothing wrong with my code, as I am a novice and object orientation can leave me a little confused

```
<?php


class SignUp {

    private $email;
    private $password;


    public function setEmail($e) {
        $this->email = $e;
    }

    public function getEmail() {
        return $this->email;
    }

    public function setPassword($p) {
        $this->password = $p;
    }

    public function getPassword() {
        return $this->password = password_hash($_POST['password'], PASSWORD_BCRYPT);
    }
}

$obj = new SignUp();
$obj->setEmail($_POST['email']);
$obj->setPassword($_POST['password']);
```

Comment: You should hash the password in the setter, and rename the `getPassword()` method to `getPasswordHash()` to make it clear that it is the hash, not the original password.

Comment: So what you meant is that I need to use this in the setter: **$this->password = password_hash($p, PASSWORD_BCRYPT);** ?

Comment: That's correct.